# Importing an object with reusable tailwindCSS classes from another .ts file and using its key values in a Nextjs React component does not seem to work

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Im trying to import an object containing reusable TailwindCSS classes and reuse these classes across my app. For some reason I need to copy + paste this object locally INSIDE the react component I want to use it in for it to work.

```
// constants.ts (I want to reuse this object eg. (className={ElementTypeColors[type]}))

export const ElementTypeColors: { [key in IElementType]: string } = {
    'alkali metal': 'bg-lime-400 dark:bg-lime-800',
    metalloid: 'bg-yellow-400 dark:bg-yellow-900',
    actinide: 'bg-orange-400 dark:bg-orange-900',
    'alkali earth metal': 'bg-red-400 dark:bg-red-800',
    'reactive non-metal': 'bg-blue-400 dark:bg-blue-800',
    'unknown type': 'bg-gray-400 dark:bg-gray-700',
    'transition metal': 'bg-violet-400 dark:bg-violet-800',
    'noble gas': 'bg-fuchsia-400 dark:bg-fuchsia-800',
    'post-transition metal': 'bg-teal-400 dark:bg-teal-800',
    lanthanide: 'bg-sky-400 dark:bg-sky-800',
};
```

When I try to import it from a typescript constants file the classes get applied in the DOM but dont do anything style wise?

```
// Component.tsx
<Card className={`border-none p-1 col-span-1 ${ElementTypeColors[element.Type]}`}>
```

The code above only works if the `ElementTypeColors` object is declared within the component itself and does not work when importing it for another file.
This feels unsustainable. If I decide to change the color setup for 1 key in this object I need to manually change it in all the instances of this object across my app.

I'm using Next.js 14 and React 18.

Does any one know how to fix if at all possible! cheeers!

Comment: Can you add your tailwind.config.js to your question? My hunch is that its something to do with the [content configuration](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration)

Comment: @Rico Yeah sure here you go sir:

I posted it below it would not fit in this thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Rico for giving a good hint on where the bug could be. After tinkering around with the `tailwind.config.ts` file I noticed that there is a `content` array in the config file which seems to set the directories from which tailwindCSS searches the classes for you JSX.

TLDR;

```
const config = {
    ...
    content: [
        './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
        './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
        './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
        './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
        './constants/**/*.{ts,tsx}', // <- Add this to include the constants or any other custom folder in TailwindCSS's class search.
    ],
  }
...
```

Comment: Nice! Glad you were able to get it working.